# How to customize view in selected date in react native UI Kitten kit

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-ui-kitten

Does Anyone know how too customize the view of selected Date or Range in React Native Ui Kitten kit? I have done a lot of googling and still haven't found any answer. i want to select a specific date or date range and marked that date or range when button is clicked.I am New to React native and please accept my apologies if this is a silly question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Calendar component is a "controlled component" which means that it expects the application to control its state, instead of it managing itself. (See [this page from the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) for more info.)

That means that to change the selected date, you need to:

1. listen for the "onSelect" event
2. store the selected date in state
3. pass the new date back into the component.

If you're using react hooks, then you can use a `useState` hook to hold the date. For a class component you need to write a handler method to update the state. Examples of both are below.

**Using hooks:**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

import Calendar from '@ui-kitten/components';

const MyCalendar = () => {

    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());

    return (
        <Calendar
            date={date}

            {/* other props */}

            onSelect={(d)=>setDate(d)}
        />
    )

};

export default MyCalendar;
```

**Class component:**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Calendar from '@ui-kitten/components';

class MyCalendar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {date: new Date()};
    }

    handleDateChange(newDate) {
        this.setDate({
            date: newDate
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Calendar
                date={this.state.date}

                {/* other props */}

                onSelect={(date)=>this.handleDateChange(date)}
        />
    )
    }

}
```